# Passing parameters on Onsen menu

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, intel-xdk, onsen-ui

I trying to pass a parameter on Onsen menu, where at this example it works fine:

```
<body ng-controller="AppController">
<ons-sliding-menu
                  main-page="page1.html"
                  menu-page="menu.html"       

                  side="left"
                  max-slide-distance="250px"
                  var="menu">
</ons-sliding-menu>

<ons-template id="page1.html">
  <ons-page>
    <ons-toolbar>
      <div class="left">
        <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggleMenu()"><ons-icon icon="ion-navicon" style="font-size: 32px; width: 1em;"></ons-icon></ons-toolbar-button>
      </div>
      <div class="center">Page 1</div>
    </ons-toolbar>

    <p style="text-align: center; color: #999; padding-top: 100px;">
      {{ params }}
    </p>
  </ons-page>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="menu.html">
  <ons-list>
    <ons-list-item modifier="chevron" ng-click="params.msg='drink';  menu.setMainPage('page1.html', {closeMenu: true})">
      drink 
    </ons-list-item>
    <ons-list-item modifier="chevron" ng-click="params.msg='food';  menu.setMainPage('page1.html', {closeMenu: true})">
      food
    </ons-list-item>   
  </ons-list>
</ons-template>
</body>
```

JS
    ons.bootstrap()

```
app.controller('AppController', function($scope) {
    $scope.params = {};
    $scope.yourAPI = 'http://blablabla.net='+$scope.params+'&orderby=title&order=ASC';
});
```

Example here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqzrvO

The `{{ params }}` on html code works fine (just click on left menu and parameters will be passed out correctly, example: **{"msg":"drink"}** when clicked on "drink" item menu.

But when I try to change html code to display `{{ yourAPI }}` I get only **[object Object]** displayed as result.

Example here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJbXBq

How to get the correct result on that, as well as split/filter the parameter to get only "**drink**" or "**food**" keywords (without the **"msg":** )?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

This is angular binding. Just change your code:

```
<p style="text-align: center; color: #999; padding-top: 100px;">
  {{ yourAPI }}
</p>
```

to

```
<p style="text-align: center; color: #999; padding-top: 100px;">
  {{ params.msg }}
</p>
```

will solve this.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.
But what I really need to do is passing it to **$scope.yourAPI** so I can parse an URL data from Wordpress. So I need the $scope.yourAPI as something like `$scope.yourAPI = 'http://blablabla.net='+params.msg+'&orderby=title&order=ASC';` but this way it does not works...

Comment: OK, you should listen click function, The code is like this: http://codepen.io/JackieLin/pen/PqzMGe

Comment: Amazing @jackieLin I have no enough words to thank you. Anyway, THANK YOU VERY MUCH!